# Problem with inserting vectors into PineconeDB

Tags: next.js, vector, large-language-model, pinecone

I am trying to insert the vectors into by pinecone database by this lines of code:

```
console.log('inserting vectors into Pinecone');

    const namespace = pineconeIndex.namespace(convertToAscii(filekey));

    console.log("inserting vectors into pinecone");
    await namespace.upsert(vectors);

    return documents[0];
```

But i am getting the error for 'vectors' in upsert method:
`Argument of type 'Vector[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PineconeRecord<RecordMetadata>[]'. Type 'Vector' is not assignable to type 'PineconeRecord<RecordMetadata>'. Types of property 'metadata' are incompatible. Type 'object | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RecordMetadata | undefined'. Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'RecordMetadata'.`

I am expecting to insert my vectors in pinecone database in next.js. If any others methods are known please let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.